# jquery pop window suceed but pass parameter failed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create a web project and inside it there is a JSP.The code is below:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%String option=request.getParameter("option");
out.println("option is"+option);
%>>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>First Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/TestWebsite/dwr/engine.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="/TestWebsite/dwr/interface/SAPget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/TestWebsite/dwr/util.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
function bclick()
{
    alert (option);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <button type="button" onclick="bclick()">getit</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Then I call it with below code

```
jQuery.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/TestWebsite/1.jsp',
  data:{option:"12345678"},
  success: function(data) {
    window.open("/TestWebsite/1.jsp");
  }
});
```

It opened the jsp in a new window but the option in the newly opened jsp is null. Then how to pass the parameter to new opened page? Thx.

Comment: Do you want to pass the `{option:"12345678"}` into the `window.open("/TestWebsite/1.jsp");` ?

Comment: @FirmanPutra Yes. That's what I want. Actually this is a simplified versionI,I have another string array parameter to pass so I can't use URL.

Comment: What if you use cookie instead? when opening a new window it should be able to get the cookie

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can use [jQuery.param()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) to create query string from your parameters then append it to the url in `window.open`. Something like:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/TestWebsite/1.jsp',
  data: {option:"12345678"},
  success: function(data) {
    window.open("/TestWebsite/1.jsp?" + $.param(your_params));
  }
});
```

Comment: Thx.I will try it. If my param is two string arrays instead, option1:{"A","B","C"},option2:{"C","D","E"}. Can I still use it?